# curl only works with -u but not with -n

Tags: bash, email, script, imap, curl

I can't get where is the error

This works like a charm:

```
~$ curl -u 'foo@yahoo.com:123' imaps://imap.mail.yahoo.com:993 -X 'STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES)'
```

But this don't:

```
~$ curl -n imaps://imap.mail.yahoo.com:993 -X 'STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES)'
```

curl 8.0.1 from snap on Ubuntu 23.04

netrc file:

> machine imap.mail.yahoo.com
>
> login foo@yahoo.com
>
> password 123

I used verbose and it shows this:

> Couldn't find host imap.mail.yahoo.com in the (nil) file; using defaults
>
> [a bunch of stuff here]
>
> curl: (21) Quote command returned error

I have already tried everything (like changing netrc permissions, placing it's credentials inside quotes, etc.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `...(nil) file...` sounds to me that it doesn't have the path to your .netrc file. Possible? Try `--netrc-file /user/example/.netrc` where the path is the path where your .netrc file is located. Also, if it's a permissions issue, try running the `curl` command with `sudo`

Comment: I tried both. Same results. :(

Comment: Even when pointing it to the file it says `nil file`?

Comment: No, it says "Couldn't find host imap.mail.yahoo.com in the /home/usuario1/.netrc file; using defaults"

Comment: But shows that same error in the end

Comment: Error in the end doesn't really matter if we can see the error right in the beginning that it doesn't pick up the .netrc file.

Comment: If I use `--config` followed by the path to a file containing `user = foo@yahoo.com` it works, but what I really want is to understand why netrc doesn't.

Comment: TBH I'd be afraid of a typo (or incorrectly pasted) domain in the .netrc file. Can you try saving a new .netrc file manually typed the host and run it with --netrc-file pointed to that file? If it fails it'd be helpful if you can share a screenshot of ls -l the netrc file, cat the netrc file, the curl command with the --netrc-file

Comment: Can you try adding a new line (maybe enter another fake machine and login) after this one? I've seen some reference that curl expects a carriage return after the login info.

Comment: You can also try an `strace' similar to what's done in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114808/302131, that'd show you what the system reads/parses from the .netrc file

Comment: strace result: https://0bin.net/paste/xSKQLeZu#1-qMfX9dTtTJwmbdGxanPKuiF5qp9idxzbSm+eOaqlM

Comment: I've recently tested on a virtual machine (https://www.onworks.net/os-distributions) and the error doesn't exist

Comment: System language is in Portuguese so can't read it fully, but from the `strace` it doesn't seem like it even access the `.netrc` file at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution!
And its weird, because I found no mention to this anywhere. It's not documented, but I just added a space before "login" and before "password", leaving the netrc file different from what is officially recommended here https://web.archive.org/web/20230516192213/https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc#example

The idea came from looking at other users files here https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/3455

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seems like this problem can only occur on systems that share specific settings. I don't know exactly what triggers it, because I have been trying to reproduce this on other systems with different configurations but had no success.